# Restoring database with .sql.gz file in odoo9 shows error

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have stored the backup of my database as an **sql.gz**,but i cannot restore it, i tried restoring it with "`restore database`" option by odoo9 UI and it gave me this error. i even tried restoring a `dump.sql` file,but same error.

**Error:**

```
Database restore error: Postgres subprocess 
     ('/usr/bin/pg_restore', u'--dbname=Backedup', 
      '--no-owner', '/tmp/tmpay5e1D') error 1
```

Comment: "_i tried restoring it..._" Let's see that part of your code. Paste that in the question.

Comment: This sounds off-topic to me! Just an idea: did you try to restore it manually without the ui?

Comment: i dnt know how to manually restore it, that is why i need a solution @ventiseis

Comment: there was no code, i tried doing it with "restore database" option @progyammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a restore is more easily achieved using the psql command. If the contents of your sql file seem to be ok, you might try loading it as a simple file containing SQL commands. See documentation in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE for example.